# getting null object reference in Bundle getExtras() method

Tags: android

I am creating an app which captures image from camera and saves image in a file. In **onActivityResult()** method i am getting null object reference error.
My Fragment class is here:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
private static final String JPEG_FILE_PREFIX = "IBR_";
private static final String JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX = ".jpg";
File photoFile = null;
ImageButton camera_button;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    camera_button = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.camera);
    camera_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
            if (cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    Log.i("File error", "File");
                }
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        fileUri);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), photoFile.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        camera_button.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }

}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = JPEG_FILE_PREFIX + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File imageF = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, storageDir);
    return imageF;
}
```

}

Actually i am getting error in this line **Bundle extras = data.getExtras();** 
Any suggestion how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` then no thumb pick is returned in intent extra - in activityOnResult - you have to read manually filepath you have provided as MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT.

You can read in docs for [ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE):

> The caller may pass an extra EXTRA_OUTPUT to control where this image will be written. ***If the EXTRA_OUTPUT is not present, then a small sized image is returned as a Bitmap object in the extra field**.

Comment: Any hint how can i do that?

Comment: Actually it should be saved in the path that is returned from `createImageFile()`, you can copy it to your own location, to get its InputStream use following code: `InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);`

Comment: Actually I have solved that using Uri. Anyway thanks for your answer.